# Netbeans 8.2 installer fails on Windows 7

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Getting

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 
 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2"): 
 CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedat 
 java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

I tried downloading and installing netbeans and the JDK bundle and still getting this. Might be netbeans independent but my system that's causing it.

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using? Also, when do you see that exception - during installation, or when you try to start NetBeans after  installation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Note the location of the installer.
2. Open a Command Prompt running as administrator:
   2.1. Go to Start button > All Programs > Accessories
   2.2. Right click Command Prompt
   2.3. Select Run as administrator
3. In the Command Prompt use the cd command to change to the directory containing the installer.
4. Execute the following command to extract the contents of the installer: [Note: You might need to change the name of the installer to match the one you have.]
      netbeans-8.2-ml-java-windows.exe  --extract

Execute the following command to manually execute the installer:
       java  -jar  bundle.jar

You will see rapid scrolling output in the Command Prompt window for a few moments, then the installer window will appear to begin the installation process.

Once Netbeans is installed on Windows 7, you may also need to run Netbeans as an Administrator--especially for database, web application and web services development, which each require server resources.

[Source](http://www.deitel.com/Books/Java/JavaHowtoProgram8eEarlyObjectsVersion/ProblemsInstallingNetbeansonWindows7/tabid/3550/Default.aspx)